# Font Family does not work in ListItemText

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Why fontFamily does not work below?

```
<ListItemText style={{fontFamily:"Times New Roman"}} primary="Sent mail" />
```

But if I add color it works.
Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3u1d

Is it possible to add my own font family to ListItemText?

Cheers,

Comment: Which font-family were you trying to add?

Comment: No matter, just try to add any font family. @m4n0

Comment: You probably need to first load the font that you want to use. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, I am rebuilding the project. And it does not work on codesandbox which I send. @Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using material-ui library, and the solution is hidden in their API:

https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/#props

Just use disableTypography prop in ListItemText Component

Here is a modified example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pedw3?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thank you very much Ruslan, I appreciate!. I did not know this prop. Thank you! @Ruslan Elisha

Comment: @mocco My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Try using font-family instead of fontFamily.

Comment: No it does not work. '"font-family"' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'